# change import path from copied file in kotlin android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, composable

I am importing a composable screen to my app. I copied the code from another app and autoimport suggests this copied path instead of the new path for my file:
`import com.example.bettehomes.screens.map.MapScreen`
but the autoimport suggests the path to copied file.

```
import com.android.geomarker.screens.map.MapScreen
composable(MAP_SCREEN) {
    MapScreen(openAndPopUp = { route, popUp -> appState.navigateAndPopUp( route,popUp) })
  }
```